# Distributed minio with one disk at each node

Tags: linux, administrator, minio

Did I understand correctly that when minio in a distributed configuration with a single disk storage classes work as if it several disks on one node? And what is this classes essentially do? How i can set what a type of storage class should use?

Thanks